# IE 7,8 form not submitting after adding onClick event

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-7

I updated some code on my website now the form will not submit for IE7 and IE8.

The code is:

```
 $(".advancedFinder .goBtn").click(function () {

        $('#validDestination').hide();

        if ($('#DestinationId').val() == '') {
            $('#validDestination').show();

            return false;
        }

        $('.indicator').show();
        return true;

    });
```

The website with the problem can be viewed at http://gocruising.com.au/  when you click the GO Button under "Advanced Cruise Finder" it call the code ok, but never submits the form. All other browsers seem to work ok.

Javascript is on layout.js line 249

Comment: If it's a form submission, I'd use [submit()](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) on the form, instead of click() on the button, otherwise IE won't submit when you hit "enter" instead of clicking. Don't know if that will have any bearing on your actual problem, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE may need the `type` attribute on the button. Try:

```
<button class="goBtn" type="submit">Go</button>
```